# Is this recommended to use private static Dictionary<string, string> for caching?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, caching

I am using a private and static, Dictionary to cache the menu name.

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> menuItemCache = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

and the cache is updated by my [POST] action method for any new menu item added. And the dictionary is holding menu names all the time, and are being consumed by other [GET] action methods.

My question is about using static dictionary instead of any other caching technique, if it is recommended to do so.

Comment: You could use a `ConcurrentDictionary` instead which is at least thread-safe which is very important in your scenario. But it will be shared by all requests.

Comment: If you need to shared menus to all users/sessions then your cache policy seems ok to me, u can change this to ConcurrentDictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be very careful with static variables. Static variables are shared across all sessions. If you intend to keep a cache per-user, you should use the `Session` object instead.

On itself, there is nothing wrong in keeping a cache stored in a dictionary. The dictionary has fast lookups, so when using a dictionary over a list you will probably benefit from that performance-wise.